# Get 1 hour to end records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've got a query like this

```
SELECT *
FROM IPS_LIST
ORDER BY EXPIRE_DATE DESC
```

I need to get the records where `expire_date` remain last 1 hours. I tried many things like DATEDIFF and its works but I have records with datetime 2099-..-... and it shows them too.

I need a query for

```
select *
from ips_list 
where EXPIRE_DATE records within the last hour
```

Comment: Show us your exact attempt using datediff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have future dated records, and they should be excluded, then just exclude them in the where clause...

```
WHERE
      expire_date >= DATEADD(hour, -1, GETDATE())
  AND expire_date <                    GETDATE()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT *
FROM IPS_LIST
WHERE EXPIRE_DATE > now() - interval 1 hour
ORDER BY EXPIRE_DATE DESC;
```

Comment: `now()` is not a SQL Server function.